# Why list items image not show in jetpack compose project?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am try to learning jetpack compose, and I have list items with name and image, my project working and no problem for list name , but user images are not showing in the emulator. I do not know what I missed. Is there any solution?

**Model:**

```
   data class Data(
    var name: String,
    var image: String)
```

**Screen:**

```
@Composable
fun DataScreen() {

    val listOfData = listOf(
        Data("name1", "image1"),
        Data("name2", "image2"),
        Data("name3",  "image3"),)

    Column(
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .background(Color.White)

    ) {

        LazyColumn(
            modifier = Modifier
        ) {

            items(listOfData.size) { index ->
                DataListItem(listOfData[index])
            }}}}
```

**Item:**

```
@Composable
fun DataListItem(data: Data) {

    val context = LocalContext.current
    val painter = rememberImagePainter(
        data = data.image
    )
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.padding(5.dp)
    ) {

        Row(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .padding(5.dp)
              
        ) {
     
            Image(
                painter = painter,
                contentDescription = null,
                contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .size(32.dp)
                    .clip(CircleShape))
            
                Text(
                    text = data.name,
                    fontSize = 12.sp,
              
                )}}}
```

Comment: I see you have set strings for the images but where are you loading the actual images from?

Comment: @Tonnie, I am load from res/drawable....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All I see is a string for your image. A painter can't display an image from just a string. You also don't need to use state management for the painter since you've included the painter in a Data object that retains the state:

This code has been tested:

```kotlin
data class Data(
    var name: String,
    var painter: Painter
)

@Composable
fun DataScreen() {

    val listOfData = listOf(
        Data("name1", painterResource(R.drawable.cat_1)),
        Data("name2", painterResource(R.drawable.cat_2))
    )

    Column(
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .background(Color.White)

    ) {

        LazyColumn(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
        ) {

            items(listOfData.size) { index ->
                DataListItem(listOfData[index])
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun DataListItem(data: Data) {
    
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(5.dp)
    ) {

        Row(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .padding(5.dp)

        ) {

            Image(
                painter = data.painter,
                contentDescription = null,
                contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .size(32.dp)
                    .clip(CircleShape)
            )

            Text(
                text = data.name,
                fontSize = 12.sp,

                )
        }
    }
}
```