# Compose Image not visible

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I take uri from db and would like to show an image:

```
val uri by viewModel.uri.collectAsState()

            
Image(
      painter = rememberAsyncImagePainter(
         ImageRequest
             .Builder(LocalContext.current)
             .data(data = uri)
             .build()
          ),
          contentDescription = ""
 )
```

but it is not loading - it is blank.

When debugging I can see that on recomposition
Image->Uri->uriString is set to correct value - "content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A44"
but itis still not visible.

It is only visible if I pick it again using:

```
val pickMedia =
    rememberLauncherForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.PickVisualMedia()) { uri ->
        if (uri != null) {
            viewModel.onImageSelected(uri)
        } else {
            Log.d("PhotoPicker", "No media selected")
        }
    }
```

I am reusing the same image in many places and from now on it is visible everywhere (but still no other image is visible until I repick it again).

After closing and reopening app images are not visible again.
Maybe it is some caching? or permissions?

Comment: Refer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72405745/6784846

Comment: Refer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71050578/6784846

Comment: Thx @AnnamalaiPalanikumar It's a hint which wll help me to resolve my issue but this is madness...